# SetWindowLong vs SetWindowLongPtr

Tags: winapi

I am new to Windows programming, and have just come across `setWindowLong` and `setWindowLongPtr()`, and I was wondering what the difference was. I have heard people say that `setWindowLongPtr()` is better, however, whenever I call it, it is just a macro defined as `setWindowLong()`.

Is there something wrong with my project?

Comment: `SetWindowLongPtr` is for setting a pointer-sized integer. If you are compiling as 32-bit, then a regular `long` is big enough.

Comment: on 64bit this is different functions. `SetWindowLong` only for set `GWL_STYLE` and `GWL_EXSTYLE`. for another - use `SetWindowLongPtr`

Comment: "*whenever I call it, it is just a macro defined as setWindowLong()*" - that is true only when compiling for 32bit, not when compiling for 64bit.

Comment: I tried compiling it for 64bit, and it worked but in my code I am using std::optional and that no longer works. do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetWindowLong()` operates on 32-bit `LONG` integers, so it is suitable only for 32bit builds, not for 64bit builds, when using options that deal with pointers (`GWL_HINSTANCE`, `GWL_USERDATA`, `GWL_WNDPROC`, `DWL_DLGPROC`, `DWL_USER`).

This is stated in the `SetWindowLong()` documentation:

> Note  This function has been superseded by the SetWindowLongPtr function. To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use the SetWindowLongPtr function.

`SetWindowLongPtr()` works with pointer-sized `LONG_PTR` integers, so it is suitable for both 32bit and 64bit builds.

This is stated in the `SetWindowLongPtr()` documentation:

> Note  To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use SetWindowLongPtr. When compiling for 32-bit Windows, SetWindowLongPtr is defined as a call to the SetWindowLong function.